# What regex can I use to match a string that consist of a word and the same word reversed

Tags: python, regex

I have to create a regex to match strings like for example: `#word##drow#, @PoOl@@lOop@, #set##tes#`.

So far my progress is `(@|#)([A-Za-z]{3,})(\1)(\1)([A-Za-z]{3,})(\1)` which of course is not doing the job, but I would like to know how to match the reversed part of the string

input example:

```
@mix#tix3dj#poOl##loOp#wl@@bong&song%4very$long@thong#Part##traP##@@leveL@@Level@##car#rac##tu@pack@@ckap@#rr#sAw##wAs#r#@w1r
```

valid output:

```
Part##traP#, #sAw##wAs#, @leveL@@Level@
```

between symbols must be letters 3 or more.
must be surrounded with @ or # only one of two

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for sharing your efforts(keep it up), could you please post samples of input and your expected output more clearly in your question to make it more clear, thank you.

Comment: Is there any max length for the words? If there is not a max length, there is no possible solution with regex.

Comment: Why regex? This can be done easily without regex.

Comment: this is sample input: @mix#tix3dj#poOl##loOp#wl@@bong&song%4very$long@thong#Part##traP##@@leveL@@Level@##car#rac##tu@pack@@ckap@#rr#sAw##wAs#r#@w1r .

Comment: Have to be regex because there are symbols as well. I know how to match the rest of it. I don't know how to match the reverse part. The valid output is #Part##traP#, @leveL@@Level@

Comment: Without regex, one can start by finding a pair, then attempt to expand the match both ways, until a closing is encountered

Comment: Another approach is to check #...# like #word# first, then check if #drow# is found at a matching position right after it (check string length and substrings). Or maybe just check #word# first then verify that #word##drow# is actually found

Comment: Why is `#car#rac#` not a valid result?

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann looks like OP's requirement is more strict than just a palindrome, it's  "A + reverse of A"

Comment: Is the valid output `#Part##traP#, @leveL@@Level@`, as in comment, OR `Part##traP#, #sAw##wAs#, @leveL@@Level@`, as in Q?

Comment: #car#rac must be #car##rac to be valid

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to create a [Deterministic Finite Automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) to match with your required state. So the asnwer is **It is impossible**.

But if there is a max length for the characters of the words, this problem can be solved with multiple DFAs. Assume that the words are exactly 3 characters:

```py
In [1]: import re                                                                                                                                                                                                  

In [2]: pattern = r'([#@])(\w)(\w)(\w)\1{2}\4\3\2\1'

In [3]: re.match(pattern, '#set##tes#')                                                                                                                                                 
Out[3]: <re.Match object; span=(0, 10), match='#set##tes#'>
```

We are taking each character separately and checking the reverse sequence of them in the input string. We can create a pattern generator and check it for multiple lengths:

```py
In [87]: def create_patterns(min_length, max_length):
    ...:     return (
    ...:         "([#@])" + "(\w)"*i + "\\1{2}" +
    ...:         ''.join(f"\\{j}" for j in range(i+1, 0, -1))
    ...:         for i in range(min_length,max_length+1)
    ...:     )
    ...:

In [5]: any(re.match(pattern, '#seeet##teees#') for pattern in create_patterns(3,6))                                                                                                                                 
Out[5]: True
```

Comment: I misread the task objectives. Now the things looks different. Basically I need to find the strings that are matching the symbols and the length of the words and then to check if the second word group is matching the first one when it is reversed. So the task is clear. I would like to say tank you to all of you. @qrsngky and Mohammad Jafari thank you because your comments made me take a better look on the task objectives.